# How to pass a voidcallback

Tags: flutter, callback, void, animator

I'm working with the Animator and I'm creating my own class.
I'm trying to pass a function to endAnimationListener, but with bad results:

```
class AnimatedFade extends StatelessWidget {
  final Duration _duration;
  final VoidCallBack _action;
  AnimatedFade(this._thidation, this._action);

  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Animator(
              duration: _duration,
              endAnimationListener: (_) => _action,
```

and the way how I pass it it's just:

```
 () {....}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
class AnimatedFade extends StatelessWidget {
  final Duration _duration;
  final VoidCallBack _action;
  AnimatedFade(this._thidation, this._action);

  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Animator(
              duration: _duration,
              endAnimationListener: (_) => _action(),
```

this means when the animation ends, execute the voidcallback function you defined